# Online bash script that calls another script ignore functions and commands

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script which downloads another script. To run the first script, I use

```
curl -s get.domain.com | bash
```

I use the following script to download:

```
#!/bin/bash

setup_dir=$(dirname "$(readlink -f $0)")
setupbuild=$vmsetup_dir/setupbuild
fileslocation=files.domain.com

wget -r -np -nH -A .sh ${fileslocation} -P ${setupbuild}
find ${setupbuild} -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} +

exec ${vmsetupbuild}/menu.sh
```

At the end of the script, I want to run the downloaded script. This is where things go wrong and I don't understand it at all.

The menu of the called script seems to work. However, when a choice is made, the echo is ignored and the exit also doesn't do anything.

If I start the script from the prompt, everything works as expected.

I have tried to put an if in various places, but that also didn't help. It seems like certain things in the called script are being ignored.

menu.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

main_menu() {
  clear
  echo "1) Option 1"
  echo "2) Option 2"
  echo "3) Other option"
  echo "4) Quit"
  read -p "Enter your choice: " main_menu_choice
  case $main_menu_choice in
  1)
    option1
    main_menu
    ;;
  2)
    option2
    main_menu
    ;;
  3)
    other_option
    main_menu
    ;;
  4)
    echo "Exit"
    exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Invalid option. Please try again."
    sleep 2
    main_menu
    ;;
  esac
}

option1() {
  echo "You chose option1."
  sleep 2
}

option2() {
  echo "You chose option2."
  sleep 2
}

other_option() {
  echo "You chose other option."
  sleep 2
}

main_menu
```

Comment: Standard input of the script is connected to the pipe, not the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is reading standard input from the pipe, so you can't respond to prompts from the terminal.

When it executes `menu.sh` you can redirect input back to the terminal.

```
exec ${vmsetupbuild}/menu.sh < /dev/tty
```